# How to create a better UI in liferay

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I am working on liferay 6.2, I created a site but this basic liferay UI is not looking good.
Can anyone tell be how to create a better UI in liferay.
I want to create a more appealing user interface with liferay.

Comment: Your question will likely be [closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions), because it is to broad. Please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and narrow your question down. Maybe you are just searching for a link to [Liferay Theming](https://www.liferay.com/de/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/development/-/ai/creating-themes-and-layout-templates-liferay-portal-6-2-dev-guide-09-en)?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own custom theme.You can go through liferay theme creation documents.

Also you can get many ready-made themes from liferay marketplace.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Liferay SDK, Eclipse or Liferay Developer Studio.  You can create your own theme and here is the guideline:

https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development/-/ai/creating-a-the-4